# Variable and number issues with adding

Tags: javascript

I have a small script I've attached to a text based game, and I'm trying to get a functioning money system running. However, I'm having an issue with the variables keeping numbers on track. I'm very new to Javascript, so I don't know too much yet, and I'd appreciate some help.

```
const modifier = (text) => {
  var money = Number()
  let modifiedText = text
  lowered = text.toLowerCase()
  if (lowered.includes('money')) {
    if (/take .+ money/g) {
      let moneyChange = (Math.floor(((Math.random()) * Math.log2(Math.random() * 500) * (Math.sinh(Math.random() * 5)))))
      if ((moneyChange) > 0) {
        console.log(moneyChange)
        var money = (moneyChange + money)
        console.log(money)
        modifiedText = text + (`\nYou find $${moneyChange}. You now have $${money}.`)
        return {text: modifiedText}
        console.log(modifiedText)
      } else {
          modifiedText = text + ('\nYou find no money.')
          return {text: modifiedText}
          console.log(modifiedText)
      }
    }
  }
  if (lowered.includes('your wallet')) {
    if (/check .+ wallet/g) {
        console.log(money)
        if (money == 0) {
          modifiedText = (`\nYou have no money`)
          return {text: modifiedText}
        } else {
        modifiedText = (`\nYou have $${money}`)
        return {text: modifiedText}
        }
    }
  }
  return {text: modifiedText}
}
modifier(text)
```

Basically what this script is supposed to do is pull the text that I've entered into the game, read it for certain words, decide what I'm trying to do, and using the variables I have it's supposed to let me take and keep track of money. The first part with taking the money seems to work, it gives me normal output like "You find $17. You now have $17." However, the second one is having issues. When I type "check your wallet" it'll not recognize that I have that $17, it just says "You have no money.", and it was saying NaN or undefined until I made the variable equal to a blank number. Been fiddling with it for a good 2 to 3 hours on and off, but I can't seem to find any solution that works. Most edits cause the values to turn into NaN or undefined.

Edit: So I'm getting comments that the code looks pretty weird. Yeah, it's cause of the way the script is interacting with the text that it's pulling. For example, the if (/take .+ money/g). The code simply doesn't work without the if for some reason. It's something due to the code of the game I'm working with, as the gameplay and a lot of the game's memory is generated on the go by the AI, and due to some stuff with the way the AI is programmed, it messes with scripting unless its VERY specific sometimes. Sorry for not clarifying.

Comment: What kind of voodoo is `if (/take .+ money/g)`? Unless I am missing some ES6 development here or something, I have no clue how that is supposed to work.

Comment: @Nick yeah, obviously - but what would be the purpose of such an `if` wrapped around it? This is not going to test or match this regex against anything, unless there is some magic I don’t know about involved here?

Comment: `var money = Number()` makes no sense. If you are just trying to define a variable it should be `var money;`

Comment: @epascarello Everytime I've put that, it starts outputting null and undefined no matter what I do, even when adding to it.

Comment: Well your random if check with a regular expression is wrong as pointed out. Should be using test or match. Not sure exactly what you are trying to do there so hard to help out.

Comment: @epascarello, I changed it to match the lowered text and it functions the exact same, I don't know for sure why if was working but oh well. As for what I'm trying to do, I'm trying to get the money variable to apply when I add the moneyChange variable to it. Right now, I do a money check and it just says I have none even after the variables are added together. The moneyChange should be adding to it, as it generates a random amount of money via that long math formula.

Comment: The check `if (/take .+ money/g) {` is not doing anything, Basically you say `is this regular expression truthy. It is doing NOTHING to check if there is a match on some entry. What do you think that if statement is doing?

Comment: Not sure. For some reason it just wasn't working in game without the if. Like I said above, I think its because of the way the AI is messing with it. To be honest, as the AI does have limitations and writes it's own memory, I'm not even sure that this is going to work without a complete code restructure.

Answer (score 0):

You never initialize `money` to anything. Since you use the variable before assigning a value to it, any calculation done with it will result in an error.

Instead of `var money = Number();` do `var money = 0;`

Further down in the code when you try to use `money` for the first time, you use the word `var` in front of it. Delete `var`. Make it

```
money += moneyChange;
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same result. Here's what the code ended up doing...
-Take the money. 
You found $5. You now have $5.
-Check your wallet. 
You have no money.

Comment: Both if statements have to be true for the wallet to report the correct amount with the way the code is written. Are you making it into each if statement when you run it?

Comment: Move the declaration of your money variable outside of the function.

Comment: After moving the money variable outside of the function, it's still doing the same things, just that for whatever reason it's giving me an undefined value despite setting it equal to 0. Even when making sure both if statements are true, it's not transferring the new value to the variable when performing the wallet check. If I do the first action multiple times just to add moneyChange multiple times, it still only says the most recent moneyChange value.